# Create MPMoviePlayer as paused

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayer

I'm trying to create an MPMoviePlayer as paused at appearance.
I've tried doing just a regular pause, as a selector with 0.1s delay, let NSNotificationCenter pause it as soon as the movie started (This did work, but with a slight delay. The movie played for a second before paus).

Is there a way to keep it paused from first appearance?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for taking y'alls time...
A friend helped me just after I posted the question.

Apparently there is a property called `shouldAutoplay` that I missed in the documentation.

Just use that.

Answer (score 0):

use pause method to do it

**`[moviePlayer pause];`**

Comment: Already tried that. Seems it won't work right after the initiation, but it has to wait until the movie is buffered...